# Inverse of compact operator is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and let $T:X \longrightarrow X$ be a bijective compact operator. We can conclude $T^{-1}$ is compact?

Comment: "nomad vectorial space"?

Comment: You probably mean "normed vector space" instead of "nomad vector space"...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you mean, you have a normed vector space and a compact linear operator which is a bijection. Because it's compact and surjective, X must be a finite dimensional norm space and thus its inverse will be a finite rank operator and hence a compact operator.
That is assuming I understand correctly what you asked.

Comment: Does this work without assuming $X$ is complete?